# why $ff008000 is pure green and not $ff00FF00?

Tags: delphi

I don't understand why $ff00**80**00 is pure green and not $ff00**FF**00 (with is lime) ? I was thinking that TAlphaColor is formed of four channels (ARGB) specified as 4-byte hexadecimal number. so how $ff00**80**00 with have 80 in the g channel could be pure green and $ff00**FF**00 with have ff in the g channel can be lime ?

```
Green = TColor($008000);
Lime = TColor($00FF00);
```

Comment: AFAIU "pure" means full intensity, i.e. no transparency. Hence the first can be refferred to as pure green and the latter pure lime. Otherwise green and lime are the names of the colors represented by the rgb part.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz but i don't understand how $ff008000 could be pure green as the G channel is only 80 and not ff?

Comment: @lurker : i just take the definition of lime in the delphi source code. Green = TColor($008000); and Lime = TColor($00FF00);

Comment: @loki - As I said that's  the name of the color. The color we call green is represented by 008000.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz ooh ok I understand, just wrong name

Comment: Perhaps... If you're wondering why the color model is called RGB and not RLB, I don't know the answer for that.

Comment: `$ff008000` is pure green, but it's not the brightest pure green that can be encoded.  `$ff00FF00` is also pure green and *is* the brightest pure green that can be encoded.  The RTL decided to call the first one "Green".  Really, they're both green.  So is `$ff009200`, and `$ff00AE00` and a bunch of other colours.  Some programs will probably call `$ff00FF00` "Green" instead of "Lime", surely - it's just a name, though, you could call any of them "Green" if you wanted.  `$ff40C040` is also a green, albeit not pure - whatever you want to name it really isn't that consequential.

Comment: Vox did an [interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMqZR3pqMjg) on the naming of colours - perhaps it would be enlightening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naming of the colors is what is giving you a difficulty.

Instead of the RGB color model, think of the HSB (Hue, Saturation, Brighness - also known as HSL - Hue Saturation - luminance) color model.

In that model the amount of color is given by the Saturation, and the 'color' is given by the Hue, so any color with the same value for Hue and Saturation can be said to be the same color even though they won't look the same if the brightness is different.  We could say that a fully saturated color is 'pure' but we still have colors that look different because of the different brightness levels.

Pure is just a label here, they could have called it 'only' to have the same meaning.